# Perl Regex Syntax?

Tags: regex, perl

In a program I found regex code that looks like this:

```
if ($code =~ m{ ^ \s* $ }xsi)  ...
```

I couldn't find anything about that, every tutorial only tells about this syntax:

```
if ($code =~ m/ ^ \s* $ /xsi))  ...
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: That's the same - see [perlop - Quote and Quote-like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: Well, not every tutorial. We show alternate delimiters in [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter used by the regex match operator doesn't need to be `/`; that's merely the one that allows the leading `m` to be omitted.

The following are all equivalent:

```
/.../
m/.../
m"..."
m!...!
m{...}
```

See [Quote and Quote-like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in perlop.